# Filter DataGridView via C# textbox with each word as a filter

Tags: c#, advanceddatagrid

Please I wanted to filter the grid view based on each word of the text box. where the filter has to search the data-grid each time I add a word consecutively. But in the code below it ends returning the search only depending on the last word.  Please note that I am using a data grid view.

Any Advise

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        int count = textBox1.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Count();
        label68.Text = count.ToString();
        string[] nameParts = textBox1.Text.Split(' ');
        int cnlp = 1;

        while (cnlp <= count)
        {
            string loopcount = nameParts[(cnlp - 1)];
            lbtest5.Text = loopcount.ToString();
            var bd = (BindingSource)dgvShopDrawings.DataSource;
            var dt = (DataTable)bd.DataSource;
            dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("DrawingID like '%{0}%' or title like '%{0}%'  or  level like '%{0}%'", lbtest5.Text.Replace("'", "''"));
            dgvShopDrawings.Refresh();
            ShopDrawingRecordCount = dt.Rows.Count;
            SdDgvStatusCount.Text = String.Format("Records In {0} / {1} ", dgvShopDrawings.Rows.Count, ShopDrawingRecordCount);
            cnlp = cnlp + 1;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing your RowFilter each iteration, so of cource it shows only the last one.

Try something like this instead:

```
        int count = textBox1.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Count();
        label68.Text = count.ToString();
        string[] nameParts = textBox1.Text.Split(' ');
        int cnlp = 1;

        string rowfilter = "";
        while (cnlp <= count)
        {
            string loopcount = nameParts[(cnlp - 1)];
            lbtest5.Text = loopcount.ToString();
            if (rowfilter.Length > 0) rowfilter += " AND ";
            rowfilter += tring.Format("(DrawingID like '%{0}%' or title like '%{0}%' or level like '%{0}%')", lbtest5.Text.Replace("'", "''"));
            cnlp = cnlp + 1;
        }

        var bd = (BindingSource)dgvShopDrawings.DataSource;
        var dt = (DataTable)bd.DataSource;
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = rowfilter;
        dgvShopDrawings.Refresh();
        ShopDrawingRecordCount = dt.Rows.Count;
        SdDgvStatusCount.Text = String.Format("Records In {0} / {1} ", dgvShopDrawings.Rows.Count, ShopDrawingRecordCount);
```

Comment: The search should like the below
textBox1 : john class 900
so I want the grid view to filter for the row having  ( john and class and 90 )

Comment: @FirasS then you should use "and" operator instead of "or" operator in line:  if (rowfilter.Length > 0) rowfilter += " OR "; and enclose string.Format(..filter text here..) in braces

Comment: I edited the answer. Also, is DrawingID column in your table int or string?

Comment: ALL are strings

Answer (score 0):

`RowFilter` returns latest applied filter that's why you are getting last applied filter (last word in text box) . Use `in` condtion for `RowFilter` instead of `=`. create `in` condition compatible string in loop and apply it on datatable outside the loop.

try and change code accordingly. I changed posted code with `in` condition. may be some compilation error as i didn't compiled.

```
string RowFilter="";
         int count = textBox1.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Count();
         label68.Text = count.ToString();
         string[] nameParts = textBox1.Text.Split(' ');
         int cnlp = 0;
            while (cnlp < nameParts.Count())
        {
            string loopcount =nameParts[cnlp];

          RowFilter+="'" +  loopcount + "',";


            cnlp = cnlp + 1;
        }

            if (RowFilter != "")
                RowFilter = RowFilter.Substring(0, RowFilter.Length - 1);

            var bd = (BindingSource)dgvShopDrawings.DataSource;
            var dt = (DataTable)bd.DataSource;
            dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("DrawingID in ({0}) or title in ({0})  or  level in ({0})", RowFilter);
            dgvShopDrawings.Refresh();
            int ShopDrawingRecordCount = dt.Rows.Count;
            SdDgvStatusCount.Text = String.Format("Records In {0} / {1} ", dgvShopDrawings.Rows.Count, ShopDrawingRecordCount);
```

Comment: I am new to C# please can you explain more

Comment: Sorry Bro, but it did filter as the criteria. may be I did not explain well , Please see the below: 
The search should like the below textBox1 : john class 900 so I want the grid view to filter for the row having ( john and class and 90 )

Comment: Search values can be in any columns (DrawingID , title , level) in a row? Please add screen shots , if possible.

Comment: Change  `DrawingID in ({0}) or title in ({0})  or  level in ({0})` to `DrawingID in ({0}) and title in ({0})  and  level in ({0})` and check